# Different renderings using ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-templates, angularjs-ng-if

I have a JSON feed which provides a list of search results - The list contains products and regular pages. When rendering the list, the products has a different rendering than the regular pages, which means, different HTML if it is a product or a page.
How would I achieve this? Is it possible to do something like:

```
<ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                                    <div ng-if="item.type == 'product'>PRODUCT HTML HERE</div>
                                    <div ng-if="item.type == 'page'>PAGE HTML HERE</div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

If not, how to I achieve different renderings in a ng-repeat ?

Comment: It is possible to do it differently. Did you try your approach, does it work for you?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: Please try before asking. Yes it should work but now you will get all sorts of variations just for the sake of people wanting to provide answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better you should use `ng-include` here / [**`ng-switch`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in items">
           <div ng-include="item.type == 'product'? 'product.html': 'page.html'></div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @nuffsaid Glad to help you..Thanks :)